# how to use update progress in in Telerik?

Tags: telerik

how to use update progress in Telerik? I am using telerik RadAjaxManager in my application. I  have tried with RadAjaxLoadingPanel. But it's not working.

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-loadingpanel-animation.html
this link has solved my problem.....